# prove cross ratio of 4 point on a circle is invariant

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, cross-ratio

The text which I was reading said that
if we assume points
$\displaystyle O_{1} ,O_{2} ,A,B,C,D$ on a circle then it's cross ratio is
$\displaystyle R( O_{1} A,O_{1} B;O_{1} C,O_{1} D)=R( O_{2} A,O_{2} B;O_{2} C,O_{2} D)$

please explain what does the above mean(by expressing in ratio) and give its proof.

Comment: You can refer EGMO chapter 9.

Comment: EGM0=Euclidean Geometry for Mathematical Olympiads...

Answer (score 1):

The cross ratios you are giving are cross ratios of pencils of four lines (four lines passing through the same point). The definition of the cross ratio of lines $(L_1,L_2,L_3,L_4)$ is based on the theorem saying that whatever the line cutting the pencil, the (ordinary) cross ratio of intersection points $(I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4)$ has always the same value.

See for example [this reference.](https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Bill.Triggs/pubs/isprs96/node30.html)

The value of the cross ratio of 4 lines can also be computed "intrinsically" by **using angles** as given for example [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Cross-Ratio.shtml), with their notations:

$$(\sin(cMa)/\sin(cMb))/(\sin(dMa)/\sin(dMb))$$

Consider the following figure (using your notations):

[image]

The two cross ratios are the same because the four angles involved in each one are the same (and therefore their sines as well). This comes from the classical theorem saying that, in a circle, inscribed angles subtended by the same arc are equal (for example the two angles $\alpha$ are equal because they are both subtended by arc $AB$).

Comment: But this is a circle not a straight line. Why does it work here? I think this deserves an explanation.

Comment: @wilsonw The OP means [**cross ratios of pencils of lines**](https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Bill.Triggs/pubs/isprs96/node30.html), a generalisation of simple cross ratios of points on a same line. This a number attached to the pencil of four lines in a certain order, just as the ordinary cross-ratio is a number attached to four aligned points ranked in a certain order.

Comment: I think that also means the OP's equation is the result of a wrong definition?

Comment: @wilsonw I don't see it as a definition but as a property , consequence of a definition coming frome elsewhere, as I have explained.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I understand finally whats happening now.